# metadata query failed for: api/breeze/metadata;Nan on server only. In hot towel application

Tags: iis, breeze, durandal, hottowel

I have developed one application in SPA using HotTowel. The application is running well on localhost. But When I uploaded on IIS server. It showing following error:

**"metadata query failed for: api/breeze/metadata;Nan"**

Comment: Sounds like you set your iis up incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your SPA is deployed to a Virtual Application in IIS have you tried adding the name of the application to your service name

if your url is www.test.com/myapp

```
 var dataService = new breeze.DataService({
            serviceName: '[myapp]/api/breeze',
            hasServerMetadata: true
        });
```

Just a shot in the dark.